# Identification of asian seal on painting (Characters identified: 爲善最樂)

Tags: character-identification, seal

I've got some old asian paintings from which I totally ignore the artist's name or calligraphy meaning and I'd be happy if I could get some help. You can zoom to increase quality.

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: "爲善最樂", where are these characters? The name of the artist is 徐泓.

Comment: 爲善最樂 is what the seal says. What's the question here?

Comment: @monalisa You have answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the text is “竹外一支斜・埜人家” & “徐泓” above the seal “爲善最樂”

the scroll is named “徐泓花鳥屏”

the meaning is, roughly:

there’re bamboos, a stem [of plum blossom] slanted beyond (竹外一支斜); a house in wilderness (埜人家)

the verse is quoted from a poem “昭君怨·梅花” by 鄭域 in 宋 dynasty

> 道是花來春未・道是雪來香異・竹外一枝斜・野人家

埜 (u+57dc) is a variant of 野 (u+91ce) nowadays; well, it’s used commonly in literatures of yore

“徐” is the surname, “泓” is the given name, of the author

“爲善最樂” - doing good [is the] greatest happiness

“花鳥屏” - a scroll (字畫的條幅亦稱為「屏」) of flowers & birds

have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for your help and detailed answer. So the artist's name is Xu Hong. I have a few other paintings that I will post gradually.